# why are docx files corrupted by binary post, but .doc and .pdf are fine?

Tags: pdf, asp-classic, binary, http-post, docx

I'm posting files to an API in binary format.

.pdf and .doc files are fine - they arrive in the system as expected and open up without any problems.

But for some reason, .docx files show up as corrupt.

Why would that be?

```
Sub PostTheFile(CVFile, fullFilePath, PostToURL)

    strBoundary = "---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272"
    strRequestStart = "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf &_
        "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=""file""; filename=""" & CVFile & """" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
    strRequestEnd = vbCrLf & "--" & strBoundary & "--" 

    Set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = adTypeBinary '1
        stream.Mode = adModeReadWrite '3    
        stream.Open
        stream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestStart)
        stream.Write ReadBinaryFile(fullFilePath)
        stream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestEnd)
        stream.Position = 0
        binaryPost = stream.read
        stream.Close

    Set stream = Nothing    

    Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        httpRequest.Open "PATCH", PostToURL, False, "username", "pw"
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=""" & strBoundary & """"
        httpRequest.Send binPost
        Response.write "httpRequest.status: " & httpRequest.status 
    Set httpRequest = Nothing   
End Sub


Function StringToBinary(input)
    dim stream
    set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Charset = "UTF-8"
        stream.Type = adTypeText 
        stream.Mode = adModeReadWrite 
        stream.Open
        stream.WriteText input
        stream.Position = 0
        stream.Type = adTypeBinary 
        StringToBinary = stream.Read
        stream.Close
    set stream = Nothing
End Function

Function ReadBinaryFile(fullFilePath) 
    dim stream
    set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = 1
        stream.Open()
        stream.LoadFromFile(fullFilePath)
        ReadBinaryFile = stream.Read()
        stream.Close
    set stream = nothing
end function
```

**Update:**

Added in Stream.Close as pointed out. I fully expected that to solve the problem but it didn't  :(

**Update 2:**

I've been testing with different stream modes and encodings, but nothing I try gives me any joy.

I've also tried debugging the DOCX document. I've been through all the xml files within the document looking for invalid xml - I thought this might give me a clue as to where it's going wrong, but it all comes out as valid.

[How can I debug a corrupt docx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193687/how-can-i-debug-a-corrupt-docx-file)

Answer (score 1):

The file type of docx file is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document".
So you can solve this problem by defining nvarchar(max) for data type in your datasource table.

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the stream after reading the binary file

```
function ReadBinaryFile(fullFilePath) 
    dim stream
    set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = 1
        stream.Open()
        stream.LoadFromFile(fullFilePath)
        ReadBinaryFile = stream.Read()
        stream.Close 'here
    set stream = nothing
end function
```

Comment: Thank you meda, I totally missed that. They're still coming out as corrupt though so there must be another issue also. :(

Comment: How can I test your file did you put the whole code in your post?

Comment: Yes, that was all the code.  There were a couple of functions to get the file / directory path etc. But while I was getting it working I've just been hard coding these values.

Comment: Different question, regarding the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193687/how-can-i-debug-a-corrupt-docx-file