# Are there any docx repair tools that give a meaningful error message?

Tags: docx

I am struggling to find the cause of a corrupt docx file.

It seems that there are *millions* tools out there for repairing corrupted files - I've tried 5 that all repaired beautifully, but none of them gave any indication of the error origin.

Does anybody know of one that does?

Open source would be a bonus.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I tried using the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool as recommended by frankpl. It looked promising, but it refused to open my corrupt file either standalone or to compare with another.

I found a difference between the [Content_Types].xml part of the file, but on closer   It's just the order that's different  - I presume this wouldn't account for corruption?

In the valid (repaired by Word) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/document.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/stylesWithEffects.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-word.stylesWithEffects+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/settings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/webSettings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

And in the corrupt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
    <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/document.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/stylesWithEffects.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-word.stylesWithEffects+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/settings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/webSettings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

Comment: And another one. If you're going to downvote a question at least have the decency to explain. Or how is the OP to know any better?

Comment: There are many possible causes of corruption.  Depending on the problem, Word itself will either provide a line number into the XML (which is great), or just throw up its hands.  That's far better than Powerpoint...  The Productivity Tool also contains a tool for checking the docx against the schema, which is occasionally helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of DOCX repair tools that are free:

http://www.docxrepairtoolbox.com/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/damageddocx2txt/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickwordrecovr/

http://download.cnet.com/SysInfoTools-Docx-Repair/3000-2248_4-75330500.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, there were a couple I hadn't tried in there, but none of the 4 seemed to give error messages, which is what I require.

Answer (score 0):

Not a docx repair tool, but the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) contains a tool named "Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office" that you can use to compare two docx files (like the corrupt and the working one).

Comment: Great, that seems like what I'm after, I'll look into that now. Thanks!

Comment: For anybody coming to this question, I should mention that while the above looked highly promising, it wouldn't open my corrupt docx file, so comparison was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but just to say for anyone with similar problems.

The above content files wont be source of issue.  (order isn't an issue it's just what word does on repair - renumbers ids and reorders)

Something that can cause corruption is simply having extra files in the zip that doesn't belong there.

Most of the time when it throws it's hand up in air and doesn't give you a hint, it's the structural metadata that has gone wrong.

By that I mean, not an invalid pointer to a relationship id in the document.xml (for example), but an invalid relationship file itself.  For example, pointing to a content type in document.xml.rels that isn't in [Content_Types].xml.

However, when word repairs everything it renumbers all it's ids (and reorders) so compare tools are difficult.

Check the list of files is same, concentrate on things such as [Content_Types].xml and document.xml.rels (and other rels files), and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Many years late, but you can create your own error checker using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Validation`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497334.aspx