# What could be causing this corruption in .docx files during httpwebrequest?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, docx, corruption

I am using `httpwebrequest` to post a file with some additional form data from an MVC app to a classic ASP site.

If the file is a .docx, it always arrives as corrupted. Others seem to open fine, but it could be that their formats are more flexible.

When I open the original and corrupted files in Sublime Text, I noticed that the corrupted file is missing a block of `0000` at the end. When I manually replace this block the file opens fine.

[image]

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly in my .NET code that is causing this happen? Or is the problem more esoteric?

The classic ASP code uses [Persist's AspUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/) to receive the file. This is used in numerous places elsewhere on the receiving site and has never caused any problems before. So I don't think the error lies there. Plus, it's just a simple call, and I can't see what there is to get wrong!

`Set File = Upload.Files("fileField")`

I'm at a loss as to how to start debugging this problem further.

---

**This is the code I'm using to post the file:**

```
public async Task<string> TestFileSend()
{
    string result;

    var postToUrl = "https://www.mywebsite.com/receive-file.asp";

    Dictionary<string, string> extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    extraData.Add("colour", "red");
    extraData.Add("name", "sandra");

    var filePath = "/path-to-file/file.docx";
    byte[] fileAsByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);


    // setup data  to send
    var dataBoundry = "---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272";
    var dataBoundryAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine + "--" + dataBoundry + Environment.NewLine);

    var startOfFileData = "--" + dataBoundry + Environment.NewLine +
        @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""fileField""; filename=""file.docx""" + Environment.NewLine;

    startOfFileData += @"Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    var startOfFileDataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(startOfFileData);
    var endOfRequest = "--" + dataBoundry + "--";
    byte[] endOfRequestAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(endOfRequest);


    // perform request
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postToUrl);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + dataBoundry;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    using (var stream = await httpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in extraData)
        {
            var dataItemBytes = DataItemAsBytes(item.Key, item.Value);
            stream.Write(dataBoundryAsBytes, 0, dataBoundryAsBytes.Length);
            stream.Write(dataItemBytes, 0, dataItemBytes.Length);
        }
        stream.Write(startOfFileDataAsBytes, 0, startOfFileDataAsBytes.Length);
        stream.Write(fileAsByteArray, 0, fileAsByteArray.Length);
        stream.Write(endOfRequestAsBytes, 0, endOfRequestAsBytes.Length);
    }
    try
    {
        using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            using (Stream myData = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(myData))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        result = e.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

**Problem Solved - This is The Amended, Working Code**

Jon was bang on with his answer. I added the line he suggested immediately after writing the file stream and they now transfer without any problems.

```
public async Task<string> TestFileSend()
{
    string result;

    var postToUrl = "https://www.mywebsite.com/receive-file.asp";

    Dictionary<string, string> extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    extraData.Add("colour", "red");
    extraData.Add("name", "sandra");

    var filePath = "/path-to-file/file.docx";
    byte[] fileAsByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);


    // setup data  to send
    var dataBoundry = "---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272";
    var dataBoundryAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine + "--" + dataBoundry + Environment.NewLine);

    var startOfFileData = "--" + dataBoundry + Environment.NewLine +
        @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""fileField""; filename=""file.docx""" + Environment.NewLine;

    startOfFileData += @"Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    var startOfFileDataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(startOfFileData);
    var endOfRequest = "--" + dataBoundry + "--";
    byte[] endOfRequestAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(endOfRequest);


    // perform request
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postToUrl);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + dataBoundry;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    using (var stream = await httpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in extraData)
        {
            var dataItemBytes = DataItemAsBytes(item.Key, item.Value);
            stream.Write(dataBoundryAsBytes, 0, dataBoundryAsBytes.Length);
            stream.Write(dataItemBytes, 0, dataItemBytes.Length);
        }
        stream.Write(startOfFileDataAsBytes, 0, startOfFileDataAsBytes.Length);
        stream.Write(fileAsByteArray, 0, fileAsByteArray.Length);
        // *** THIS ADDITIONAL LINE IS THE KEY 
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 45, 45 }, 0, 2);
        // ***
        stream.Write(endOfRequestAsBytes, 0, endOfRequestAsBytes.Length);
    }
    try
    {
        using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            using (Stream myData = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(myData))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        result = e.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently played about with multipart/form-data and noticed it has an extra `–-` on the end of the final multipart boundary. There is an example in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238809/example-of-multipart-form-data). I *think* that is where you are losing the two bytes.

If so the solution is to add a final write to the request stream of two bytes of 45 (ASCII -).

```
stream.Write(new byte[]{45, 45}, 0, 2);
```

I can't be sure, but it looks like a good fit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Spot on - you've saved me hours - thanks very much :)