# How to fix corrupted docx files programmatically (adding missing bytes)

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, docx, corruption

I'm trying to repair a large batch of corrupted `.docx` files in classic asp.

(The files are missing bytes at the end - as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102359/what-could-be-causing-this-corruption-in-docx-files-during-httpwebrequest)).

When I look at the file in Sublime (which shows it in a hex view), the corruption can be fixed by adding `0000` to the end of the file.

[image]

But I am struggling to add those 4 zeros onto the end, programmatically.

I am attempting to use the [cByteArray](http://www.u229.no/stuff/snippets/bytearrayclass.asp) class, the usage of which is like this:

```
With oByte
    Call .AddBytes(LoadBytes(sFilePath))
    Call .AddBytes(HOW DO I GET THE BYTE VALUE OF 0000 HERE?)
    lngBytes = .BytesTotal
    ByteArray = .ReturnBytes
End With

Call SaveBytesToBinaryFile(ByteArray, sNewFilePath)
```

I can't work out how to get the `0000` value into the `.AddBytes()` method.

How can I do this? I'm a bit out of my depth and not sure if I'm even approaching this the right way.

---

**In my ignorance, here's what I have tried:**

---

Redimming `ByteArray` leaving the extra bytes empty (because I think the `0000` represent null values).

This doesn't seem to change the file at all. The new saved file is identical to the old file.

```
With oByte
    Call .AddBytes(LoadBytes(sFilePath))
    ByteArray = .ReturnBytes
End With

arrayLength = ubound(ByteArray)
redim ByteArray(arrayLength + 2)

Call SaveBytesToBinaryFile(ByteArray, sNewFilePath)
```

---

Converting `0000` from hex to bytes and adding it to the corrupted file bytes.

Again, this doesn't seem to change the file at all.

```
dim k, hexString, str, stream, byteArrToAdd
hexString = "000000"
For k = 1 To Len(hexString) Step 2
 str = str & Chr("&h" & Mid(hexString, k, 2))
response.write "<hr />" & str & "<hr />"
Next

Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With stream
 .Open
 .Type = 2       ' set type "text"
 .WriteText str  
 .Position = 0
 .Type = 1       ' change type to "binary"
 byteArrToAdd = .Read 
 .Close
End With
set stream = nothing

With oByte
    Call .AddBytes(LoadBytes(sFilePath))
    Call .AddBytes(byteArrToAdd)
    ByteArray = .ReturnBytes
End With

Call SaveBytesToBinaryFile(ByteArray, sNewFilePath)
```

---

Getting the final byte of the corrupted file, and adding it to 2 new values after redimming ByteArray.

This doesn't seem to change the file at all either!!

```
With oByte
    Call .AddBytes(LoadBytes(sFilePath))
    ByteArray = .ReturnBytes
End With


arrayLength = ubound(ByteArray)
finalByte = ByteArray(arrayLength)
redim ByteArray(arrayLength + 2)
ByteArray(arrayLength + 1) = finalByte
ByteArray(arrayLength + 2) = finalByte

Call SaveBytesToBinaryFile(ByteArray, sNewFilePath)
```

Comment: You should be able to append them using `ChrB()`, something like `Call .AddBytes(ChrB(&h00) & ChrB(&h00))` should work.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Ditto for `ControlChars.NullChar` - neither added any bytes to the file.  Do you think that it be related to this? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628175-CHR(-amp-H00)-vs-CHR-(-amp-H00)  (unfortunately no solution is provided there)

Comment: I am sorry for you man... Still using classic asp in November 2017 : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a binary file stream with the help of a user defined conversion (string to byte()) function like the following.

```vb
Function GetBytesOf(str) 'returns bytes of given string
    With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        .Type = 2 'text
        .Charset = "x-ansi" 
        .Open
        .WriteText str
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 'binary
        GetBytesOf = .Read 'returns Byte()
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Dim patch
patch = GetBytesOf(Chr(0) & Chr(0)) 'equals to WORD 0000

With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    .Type = 1 'binary
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile sFilePath
    'move cursor to the end of file
    .Position = .Size
    .Write patch
    .SaveToFile sNewFilePath, 2 '2 for overwrite if exists
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That is much simpler than anything I've tried and it works perfectly.  Much joy  :)

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox glad to help.